# Interceptor not getting invoke

Tags: java, spring-boot

Based on some business logic i need to add query parameters to the request before it reaches the controller. In order to achieve this i have use the HandlerInterceptorAdapter to intercept the request.
I have a common lib where I have defined an interceptor and the dependent project has the controllers.
The interceptor is getting registered but when i invoke any api call it does not get invoked.

Interceptor in common lib

```java
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, java.lang.Object handler)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         request.setAttribute("id", "123"); // this would be populated based on logic

        return true;
    }
}
```

Dependency

```java
@Configuration
public class Resolver implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
RequestInterceptor interceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your `Resolver` configuration really called during start up?

Comment: yes it is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to annotate the `RequestInterceptor`. Please remove the @Component annotation from `RequestInterceptor` and `@Autowired` annotation from `Resolver` class to this dependency.
Instead of injecting, please instantiate it via default constructor.

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, java.lang.Object handler)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         request.setAttribute("id", "123"); // this would be populated based on logic

        return true;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Resolver implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried the same before also but it did not work.

Comment: Have you also included the @EnableWebMvc annotation, as it is on my example? Please provide also the dependency management of the project.

Comment: By using @EnableWebMvc you will loose Spring Boot autoconfiguration.

Comment: As mentioned by @mentallurg i don't want to loose auto configuration as it plays an import part of my project.